# If I change permalink structures, can I use htaccess to permanantly redirect links?

Tags: permalinks, redirect, htaccess, seo

Ive got some super old links that have a lot of SEO juice and I dont want to lose that if I change permalink structure. This is partly due to the older version of WP i have (2.1)

I want to use post ids in the structure now, and not the slug name or maybe both

myblog.com/post/12121/slug-name

If i use htaccess for this will Google and other search engines update their links without penalizing me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need 301 redirection and you will carry on your SEO juice to the new URLs.